# Cannot add external library to android studio project

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to add https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage to my Android studio project. When i add the line:

```
compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.1'
```

to my app's `build.gradle` file, it gives me:

> Error(33, 13) Failed to resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your root `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try Latest one

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.3'
}
```

I found this answer here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2725#package

Answer (score 0):

https://jitpack.io/#jkwiecien/EasyImage/1.3.1

If you're using gradle, you need two steps: 
1. adding jitpack repository to the root build file
2. add your dependency to the EasyImage library to the app build file.